# How to create a webapp using android studio?

Tags: android, templates, web-applications, android-studio

I have tried using webviewer, using a tutorial only to discover that it opens the url in the web-browser. How do I create this app so that it displays a website inside the app?  Would I need to set it up to use html5? then throw in an iframe?

Any help would be appreciated. The 3rd party program I used to create my webapp has started to throw in popup adds and I'm losing rating because of it.

Is there perhaps an android studio -project file- i can download that has the template all setup? Where all I need to do is input the url?

Comment: can you look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: that's what i was using @Adeeb. It seems to be a lot simpler than that. using what Paritosh posted. But thank you. :) This issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create new app, take a look at [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/), [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) frameworks. If you simply want to display existing website, use `WebView` in android. Refer this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm) for `WebView` Tutorial.

Comment: Thank you. That was so much more simpler than the tutorial I followed. Haha now it works correctly. I guess I'll ask another question for your insight. If I want to include a google adsense code in a block above the webView, how would I do so?

Comment: I don't know about `adSense`. Is it `Java` code or `Javascript`? If it is `Java`, add it in Android code. If it is `Javascript`, add it in your website code.

Answer (score 0):

You dont necessary need to use 3rd party programs to do this. Android has a built in Class called `WebView` using this you can view your `WebPage` or `WebApp` inside an Android `Activity`. Have a look on [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). And it is always better to develop your own code rather than downloading ready made projects when it comes to small programs like this. Hope it helps.