# Is there a way to login to a website (like gmail) with an android app?

Tags: android, selenium, request, webdriver

so I got a website like Gmail and need to login to this website and then press a button. I want to make an app for this, where I can parse in my Username and Password and then can click on my Mobile this Button.I would need something like Selenium but I didn't find a way to use that for Android. Does anybody has a idea how I could achieve that?

Comment: I saw [this one](https://www.tindie.com/products/hugs/tapster-2/?utm_source=hackaday&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=fromstore) on hackaday recently. Also emulators and tapping apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [loging into web page from android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309029/loging-into-web-page-from-android-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all big social media company you can integrate your app to log into(Facebook, Google, YouTube, Twitter, etc...), if that's what you want, comment and I'll give you the proper guides.

from a quick search I found few question already with that purpose:

- [Android app, how to log into website and display information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727112/android-app-how-to-log-into-website-and-display-information)
- [loging into web page from android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309029/loging-into-web-page-from-android-app)
- [How to Open Any Website in Android Application in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389037/how-to-open-any-website-in-android-application-in-android-studio)
- [Android: How to programatically login to website and retrieve data from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717806/android-how-to-programatically-login-to-website-and-retrieve-data-from-it)
- [How to create a webapp using android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916368/how-to-create-a-webapp-using-android-studio)
- [Login to Web Services PHP Using Volley Library In Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlGmC2sx7uc)
- [Android / Java: Programmatically login into website with Android-App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474239/android-java-programmatically-login-into-website-with-android-app)
- [Performing login to https website via Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443401/performing-login-to-https-website-via-android-app)

again, if you need to sign into one of the big social media companies websites, comment and I'll give you their guides, they have an easy way **they** created in order to make it better for the users of their apps and websites.

also, try to find tutorials about it on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/) or [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com), there are many many free tutorials that might help you.

best of luck on your way, and don't forget to accept the answer once it helped you, and if you need any further help, comment here if it's related or make a new post about it, and don't forget to do a full research about it before.